# Display 'From Price' for categories on Magento

Tags: magento, e-commerce, categories

I'm working on a Magento site for a client and on their design it requires the sub-categories to show a 'price from' on the category.

So, in short, is it possible to get the data for the smallest value of all products within a category?

I've been searching and trying for over an hour now and not getting anywhere.

Cheers,

Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method would be most suited for a block, I haven't gotten a chance to test it yet, though it should work. For reference, the Magentos wiki post on this is pretty decent: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/catalog/using_collections_in_magento

```
$categoryModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(x); // Replace with Id of Cat

$productColl = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                                                ->addCategoryFilter($categoryModel)
                                                ->addAttributeToSort('price', 'asc')
                                                ->setPageSize(1)
                                                ->load();

$lowestProductPrice = $productColl->getFirstItem()->getPrice();
```

Might want to be placed in a try catch, if the collection for a particular category is empty, or the category fails to load, etc.

Comment: Hi Dan, sorry - only just noticed your response! I'll try this out tonight and let you know how I get on. Thanks!